# TWilio-Forward incoming SMS to emails in Rails5

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, twilio

I wanna forward all incoming messsages from my virtual twilio number to `email`
I am trying to add a webhook from the phone number settings but I didn't find any option in the `Messaging service` dropdown.[image]

And after adding this how to handle the controller code to forward sms to email.

I am using `twilio-ruby` gem and `RAILS-5`

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

A [Messaging Service](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/services) is a:

> higher-level “bundling” of messaging functionality around a common set of senders, features, and configuration. The same settings and feature configuration applies to all of the senders (long code numbers, short codes, toll-free numbers, etc.) in the Messaging Service’s pool.

So that is not the setting you are looking for in this case.

To edit the webhook URL, you need to look further down the page. You currently have an ngrok URL set as the webhook when this number receives an incoming message. This is what you should change if you want to update it.

[image: The webhook URL is set in the input under "A message comes in"]

As for receiving the messages in your Rails controller, I recommend reading this blog post on [receiving and replying to SMS messages with Rails](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/04/receive-and-reply-to-sms-in-rails.html).